# Error with undertow and spring-boot 1.4

Tags: spring-boot, undertow

I'm getting **NullPointerException** when running undertow and spring-boot 1.4.

You can see this error if you run [joinfaces-example](https://github.com/joinfaces/joinfaces-example/tree/myfaces-undertow) with

**java -jar target/joinfaces-example-2.1.3-SNAPSHOT.jar**

I realized that the error does not occur if I debug the project inside IDE (NetBeans).

More, this error started when I upgraded spring boot to 1.4. No error occurs if I change jsf-spring-boot-parent version to 2.0.0 which uses spring boot 1.3 version.

This error may occur when StartupServletContextListener is not activated. It is created by UndertowMyfacesSpringBootAutoConfiguration. Debug said it is activated:

```
   UndertowMyfacesSpringBootAutoConfiguration matched
      - @ConditionalOnClass classes found: io.undertow.Undertow,org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener (OnClassCondition)
```

Stack trace above:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.Jsp21FacesInitializer.initContainerIntegration(Jsp21FacesInitializer.java:62) ~[myfaces-bundle-2.2.10.jar!/:2.2.10]
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.AbstractFacesInitializer.initFaces(AbstractFacesInitializer.java:172) ~[myfaces-bundle-2.2.10.jar!/:2.2.10]
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener.contextInitialized(StartupServletContextListener.java:121) [myfaces-bundle-2.2.10.jar!/:2.2.10]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:187) [undertow-servlet-1.3.23.Final.jar!/:1.3.23.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:198) [undertow-servlet-1.3.23.Final.jar!/:1.3.23.Final]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.undertow.UndertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.createDeploymentManager(UndertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:390) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.undertow.UndertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(UndertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:224) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:164) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:134) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:535) [spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:369) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:313) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1185) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1174) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.joinfaces.example.JoinFacesExampleApplication.main(JoinFacesExampleApplication.java:10) [classes!/:2.1.4-SNAPSHOT]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [joinfaces-example-2.1.4-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.1.4-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [joinfaces-example-2.1.4-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.1.4-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) [joinfaces-example-2.1.4-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.1.4-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:58) [joinfaces-example-2.1.4-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.1.4-SNAPSHOT]
```

Comment: What's the stack trace of the NPE?

Comment: I've just edited the question @AndyWilkinson.

Answer (score 1):

The error is with JoinFaces Undertow starter because it was using [two versions of JspFactory class](https://github.com/joinfaces/joinfaces/issues/170).

[Duplicate Finder Maven Plugin](https://github.com/joinfaces/joinfaces/issues/172) is now used to avoid duplicated classes and resources.